# How to assign a variable value to an HTML input created in Javascript / How to style HTML elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here's the code I am currently using.

```
function firstChildAge() {
  var header = document.createElement('H1');
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY');
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("WHAT IS THE AGE OF THE FIRST CHILD?");
  var inputChildOne = document.createElement("Input");
  header.appendChild(textnode);
  document.body.appendChild(header);
  document.body.appendChild(inputChildOne);
}
```

a) How would I assign a variable value to the response created by the user to the Input?

b) How can I style elements inside Javascript? For example, how can I make the text "WHAT IS THE AGE OF THE FIRST CHILD?" red, or change the font size?

Thank you!!!

Comment: with jQuery: `$("H1").css("color","red")`. this can also be called inside a function and the function gets triggered by clicking a button or whatever

Comment: @hansTheFranz I don't really want to incorporate another language. Anyway I can do this with just JS, HTML, or CSS?

Comment: Are you trying to generate the whole html page by js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the current string of the input box using.

```
var val=document.getElementById('id of the input').value;//you can use any other element selection method too
```

to set the color you can use

```
document.getElementById('id of the tag').style.color='color name or hex';
```

You can use this to set the id of an element

```
element.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
```

Also textNodes dont have style attributes, they take the parent elements features like this

```js
var header = document.createElement('H1');
     var body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY');
     var span = document.createElement('span');
     // Set DOM property
     span.style.color = 'red';
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('WHAT IS THE AGE OF THE FIRST CHILD'));

 // Add to document
 document.body.appendChild(span);

 var inputChildOne = document.createElement("Input");

 header.appendChild(textnode);
 document.body.appendChild(header);
 document.body.appendChild(inputChildOne);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I though at first also... but where do I assign an id tag? It doesn't seem to be applicable on any of the lines?..

Comment: check my edit, you can set the id first and then use it

Comment: I'm using the following code, but nothing is working. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. `var textnode = document.createTextNode("WHAT IS THE AGE OF THE FIRST CHILD?");` `textnode.setAttribute("id", "blablabla");` `document.getElementById("blablabla").style.color="red";`

Answer (score 1):

a) you can use `document.getElementById('id of input').value = variableValue`

b) you can use `document.getElementById('id of tag').style.styleName = val`,for example, using `document.getElementById('id of tag').style.color = 'red'` to set color,using `document.getElementById('id of tag').style['font-size'] = '14px'` to set font-size

Comment: Thank you, but same question, how can I assign the text an ID? I can't figure out where to go, and I tried the method above and it didn't work.

Comment: using ```document.getElementById('id').textContent = yourText``` to set text of HTMLelement

Comment: Not how to set the text, but how to set the ID

Comment: I'm so sorry, you can use ```document.getElementById('id').setAttribute('id','idValue')```